# Advanced Custom Fields - php if field has this replace with this content

Tags: php, replace, metadata, advanced-custom-fields

In a wordpress site with ACF plugin installed, I have a custom field created on the post pages that directs you to copy/paste code generated from this site map-embed.com, to make a fast and easy way for you to show a google map location on the website.

The issue is, we do not want the map to be scrollable, but the embed code by default does not include " scrollwheel: false, draggable: false, " in the ( myOptions ) javascript area of the map

this is an example of the code it generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;"><div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style><a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.themecircle.net/photography/" id="get-map-data">themecircle</a></div><script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:14,center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.805478,-73.96522499999998),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.805478, -73.96522499999998)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>The Breslin</b><br/>2880 Broadway<br/> New York" });google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

My attempt that failed was to add a jquery find and replace custom code. It worked but only some of the time and also tossed errors.

I am trying to think of another solution, it needs to work "as is" bc he already has 100's of posts created with the embed code in the database already.

Is this a possible solution?

Example of php using ACF to display the code:

```
echo the_field('map-embed-code');
```

Is it possible to find the "meta data" in the database for that field and replace a string of the "data HTML" with some code before spitting out the code?

something like this)

```
$mapFix = get_field('map-embed-code');
    if ( $mapFix ) {
        ? find meta data ?
        ? var myOptions = { ?
        ? replace with ?
        ? var myOptions = {scrollwheel: false, draggable: false, ?

        echo the_field('map-embed-code ? with new replaced HTML ?');
    } else {
       echo 'no map code!';
    }
```

So essentially re-writing what was in the database, and adding the correct variables to the map script so scrolling no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it.. incase someone else needs a fix... i used php's string replace

```
$mapfix = get_field('office_space_map');

    if (strpos($mapfix,'myOptions = {zoom:14,') == true) {

    $mapfix = str_replace('myOptions = {zoom:14,', 'myOptions = {scrollwheel: false, draggable: false, zoom:14,', $mapfix);

    echo $mapfix;

} else {
    echo the_field('office_space_map');;
}
```